# how to get the time a person joined [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on the whois command and I was inspired by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeuuB7qiTbQ and I want to make a date like mee6

This my code

```
@bot.command(aliases=['user','info'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kdoje(ctx, member=discord.Member):
  #Datum jointu
  created_at = member.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
  #Embed
  em= discord.Embed(title=member.name, description = member.mention, color = discord.Colour.red)
  #footer
  em.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Příkaz byl vyvolán {ctx.author.name}")
```

I use this import command

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import time
import random
import json
import keep_alive
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Comment: You're looking for [`discord.Member.joined_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `member.joined_at` to get a `datetime` object from the time the member joined the server.
You can implement this in your code like this:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['user','info'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kdoje(ctx, member=discord.Member):
    #Datum jointu
    created_at = member.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    joined_at = member.joined_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")#Here you get the time the member joined at and format it, like you formatted member.created_at
    #Embed
    em= discord.Embed(title=member.name, description = member.mention, color = discord.Colour.red)
    #footer
    em.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Příkaz byl vyvolán {ctx.author.name}")
```

---

**References:**

- [discord.Member.joined_at](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at)

Comment: @GamingerPg I used your code and added the fields to the embed and sent it. I am not sure if that is what you are trieng to achieve.

Comment: I want to reach the date when the member joined @Chuaat

Comment: Yes. That was already in my answer. You can get the date when the member joined_at with `member.joined_at` @GamingerPg